# Воспроизведение мелодии в нужном режиме

Tags: java, android

Я разрабатываю приложение типа будильник.

В заданный момент запускается Activity, которая в свою очередь воспроизводит мелодию таким образом :

```
alarmSound = MediaPlayer.create(SignalActivity.this, R.raw.mysound);
alarmSound.start();
//(Где: "SignalActivity" - название активности; "mysound" - название файла мелодии)
```

Проблема в том, что при громкости на нуле, мелодии не слышно. Всё логично. Однако стандартное приложение "Таймер", при громкости 0, спокойно запускает свою мелодию (то есть её слышно).

Покопавшись в интернете я определил 6 возможных типов аудиопотоков:

- STREAM_ALARM
- STREAM_DTMF
- STREAM_MUSIC
- STREAM_NOTIFICATION
- STREAM_RING
- STREAM_SYSTEM

Предполагаю, что мне нужен режим "STREAM_ALARM", но вот как именно его внести в свой код не могу никак понять.

Планирую перейти с MediaPlayer в SoundPool, чтобы затем зациклить мелодию.
 Желателен пример с использованием SoundPool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ Andrew Levitsky частично является правильным, однако код нужно серьёзно доработать и он примет вид:

```
MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
        mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM);
        try {
            mp.setDataSource(this, Uri.parse("android.resource://"+this.getPackageName()+"/"+R.raw.mysound));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            mp.prepare();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mp.start();
```

Answer (score 1):

Вот так должно работать:

```
MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM);
mp.setDataSource(this,Uri.parse("android.resource://PACKAGE_NAME/"+R.raw.soundfile));
mp.prepare();
mp.start();
```